Nano VNA shows something that I don't understand
I have cable with connected 50 ohms resistance, the length is 54 cm. Why I have such a result?
Why is the first minimum on frequency 230 MHz, but lambda/2 = 65 cm?
If I connect 50 ohms resistance on without a cable — I will get a straight line -50 dB without maximums or minimums.




I have cable with connected 50 ohms resistance, the length is 54 cm. Why I have such a result?

Your cable's characteristic impedance \$Z_0\$ is not precisely 50 Ω — but it's pretty close.

Why is the first minimum on frequency 230 MHz, but lambda/2 = 65 cm?

RF energy propagates more slowly in a dielectric than in free space.
In this case, your cable has a velocity factor of about 83%, which is fairly typical.
